# Transform the words in a Word document

Tags: python, text-editor

This is a simple transform of a Word document to embolden the first half of each word.

I used the [`python-docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module. The environment if needed was VS Code; for now the code is working.

What I want to know is that there's a chance of some problem to occur, if not how to better clean this code. I tried, but couldn't find out a way to clean it.

The inputs and some variables are in Brazilian Portuguese.

````
from docx.shared import Pt, RGBColor, Cm
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
import re

nome_arquivo = input("Qual o nome/titulo do Projeto? ")
texto = input("Qual o texto do Projeto? ")
underlines = input("Quer sublinhar a metade mais fraca? (S/s)")

def remover_caracteres_especiais(texto):
    padrao = re.compile(r'[^\w\s]', re.UNICODE)
    texto_sem_especiais = re.sub(padrao, '', texto)
    return texto_sem_especiais

documento = Document()

paragrafo1 = documento.add_paragraph('Texto:', 'Title')

paragrafo = documento.add_paragraph('')

paragrafo.style = documento.styles.add_style("EstiloPedro", WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
paragrafo.style.font.name = "Yu Gothic"
paragrafo.style.font.size = Pt(13)

paragrafo = documento.add_paragraph('', 'EstiloPedro')

paragrafo.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.JUSTIFY

texto = texto.replace('\n', ' AAAAA ')

texto = texto.split()

for letra in texto:
    letraAl = remover_caracteres_especiais(letra)
    if len(letraAl) % 2 == 0:
        quantidadeHL = len(letraAl) / 2
        quantidadeHL = int(quantidadeHL)
        firstH = letraAl[:quantidadeHL]
        secondH = letra[quantidadeHL:]
        if letraAl == "AAAAA":
            paragrafo.add_run('\n')
        else:
            paragrafo.add_run(firstH).bold = True
            if underlines == 'S' or underlines == 's':
                paragrafo.add_run(f'{secondH}').underline = True
            else:
                paragrafo.add_run(f'{secondH}').underline = False
            paragrafo.add_run(' ').underline = False
    else:
        quantidadeHL = len(letraAl) / 2 + 1
        quantidadeHL = int(quantidadeHL)
        firstH = letraAl[:quantidadeHL]
        secondH = letra[quantidadeHL:]
        if letraAl == "AAAAA":
            paragrafo.add_run('\n')
        else:
            paragrafo.add_run(firstH).bold = True
            if underlines == 'S' or underlines == 's':
                paragrafo.add_run(f'{secondH}').underline = True
            else:
                paragrafo.add_run(f'{secondH}').underline = False
            paragrafo.add_run(' ').underline = False

documento.save(f'C:/Users/phsau/Vscode Files/Python/Textos Half Bold/Textos/{nome_arquivo} Otimizado.docx')```
````

Answer (score 1):

#### A bug

This looks like a bug:

```
firstH = letraAl[:quantidadeHL]
secondH = letra[quantidadeHL:]
```

Slicing `firstH` from `letraA1` and `secondH` from `letra` will give weird results if there are special characters in the first half of a word. For example, "e-mail" becomes "**ema**ail".

I'll hazard a guess that you're trying to not include punctuation at the end of a word when getting the word length (e.g., 'Mr.' or 'right?'). If that is the case, just remove them at the end of the word:

```
def remover_caracteres_especiais(texto):
    texto_sem_especiais = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]+\Z", '', texto)
    return texto_sem_especiais
```

Or, try using `.rstrip()`.

```
def remover_caracteres_especiais(texto):
    texto_sem_especiais = texto.rstrip('''.?,;':"!$&%''')
    return texto_sem_especiais
```

#### Wasted operations

The calculation of `firstH` and `secondH` isn't used if `letra == "AAAAA"`. Reordering the code avoids the wasted caclulation.

```
if letra == "AAAAA":
    paragrafo.add_run('\n')
    
else:
    letra = remover_caracteres_especiais(letra)
    ...
```

#### Combine even/odd branches

The only difference between handling even and odd length words is the calculation of `quantidadeH`.  Toby Speight provided a simple expression for the calculation regardless of whether the length is even or odd. An alternative is to use `math.ceil()`. Either lets the same code handle both even and odd length words.

```
for letra in texto.split():
    if letra == "AAAAA":
        paragrafo.add_run('\n')
        
    else:
        letra2 = remover_caracteres_especiais(letra)
        quantidadeHL = math.ceil(len(letra2)/2)
        firstH = letra[:quantidadeHL]
        secondH = letra[quantidadeHL:]

        paragrafo.add_run(firstH).bold = True
        paragrafo.add_run(secondH).underline = underlines
        paragrafo.add_run(' ').underline = False
```

#### All together

```
import math
import re

from docx.shared import Pt, RGBColor, Cm
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT

nome_arquivo = input("Qual o nome/titulo do Projeto? ")
texto = input("Qual o texto do Projeto? ")
underlines = input("Quer sublinhar a metade mais fraca? (S/s)").upper() == 'S'

def remover_caracteres_especiais(texto):
    """Remove trailing non-word characters (punctuation, spaces, emojis and
       any other stuff) from texto.
    """

    texto_sem_especiais = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]+\Z", '', texto)
    return texto_sem_especiais

documento = Document()

paragrafo1 = documento.add_paragraph('Texto:', 'Title')

paragrafo = documento.add_paragraph('')

paragrafo.style = documento.styles.add_style("EstiloPedro", WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
paragrafo.style.font.name = "Yu Gothic"
paragrafo.style.font.size = Pt(13)

paragrafo = documento.add_paragraph('', 'EstiloPedro')

paragrafo.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.JUSTIFY

texto = texto.replace('\n', ' AAAAA ')

for letra in texto.split():
    if letraAl == "AAAAA":
        paragrafo.add_run('\n')
        
    else:
        letra1 = remover_caracteres_especiais(letra)

        quantidadeHL = math.ceil(len(letra`)//2)
        firstH = letra[:quantidadeHL]
        secondH = letra[quantidadeHL:]

        paragrafo.add_run(firstH).bold = True
        paragrafo.add_run(secondH).underline = underlines
        paragrafo.add_run(' ').underline = False

documento.save(f'C:/Users/phsau/Vscode Files/Python/Textos Half Bold/Textos/{nome_arquivo} Otimizado.docx')
```

Note: I don't have the python-docx library installed, so the code isn't tested.

Answer (score 0):

The main loop has an `if`/`else` that differs only in the computation of `quantidadeHL`:

> ```
>     if len(letraAl) % 2 == 0:
>         quantidadeHL = len(letraAl) / 2
>         quantidadeHL = int(quantidadeHL)
> ```

> ```
>     else:
>         quantidadeHL = len(letraAl) / 2 + 1
>         quantidadeHL = int(quantidadeHL)
> ```

We can use integer division to unify these two expressions:

```
        quantidadeHL = (1 + len(letraAl)) // 2
```

---

When we have an `if`/`else` whose branches differ only in a boolean value, it's even easier to unify.  Look at this:

> ```
>             if underlines == 'S' or underlines == 's':
>                 paragrafo.add_run(f'{secondH}').underline = True
>             else:
>                 paragrafo.add_run(f'{secondH}').underline = False
> ```

We can replace that with:

```
use_underline = underlines in "Ss"  # once, before the loop
```

```
                paragrafo.add_run(f'{secondH}').underline = use_underline
```